# I'm Getting "Channel Not Found" Error on My Telegram Bot

Tags: javascript

Channel not found error in my Telegram Bot

hello, I have a telegram support bot, but it needs to log to a specific channel.
I would be very happy if you could help me. I didn't understand the error either, I've been trying to solve it for how many hours!

```
Unhandled rejection Error: ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: chat not found

at /home/runner/Near UnwrittenVoxel/node_modules/node-telegram-bot-api/src/telegram.js: 299:15

at tryCatcher (/home/runner/Near UnwrittenVoxel/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.j s:16:23)

at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/runner/Near UnwrittenVoxel/node_modules/blu

ebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)

at Promise._settlePromise (/home/runner/Near UnwrittenVoxel/node_modules/bluebird/js/re

lease/promise.js:604:18)

at Promise._settlePromise® (/home/runner/NearUnwrittenVoxel/node_modules/bluebird/js/r

elease/promise.js:649:10)

at Promise._settlePromises (/home/runner/Near UnwrittenVoxel/node_modules/bluebird/js/r

elease/promise.js:729:18)

at _drainQueueStep (/home/runner/Near UnwrittenVoxel/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/a sync.js:93:12)

at _drainQueue (/home/runner/Near UnwrittenVoxel/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async .js:86:9)

at Async._drainQueues (/home/runner/NearUnwrittenVoxel/node_modules/bluebird/js/releas e/async.js:102:5)

at Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/runner/Near UnwrittenVoxel/node_modules/b luebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.